# What kind of spider is in this pic I took?

Tags: species-identification

What kind of spider is this? [image: black and white spider]

It has a weird black and white backpack looking thing. Found a couple of them in Auburn, Alabama. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Spiny Orb Weaver, aka Spiny-backed Orb Weaver. Orb Weavers are a very large genus of spiders; this one is a Gasteracantha *cancriformis*. The spikes can be black or red; there are many colors as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pictures uploaded for you :) Feel free to change them

Comment: @Remi.b - Oh, thank you!!! I only have a phone now, and I couldn't figure out how to do it! And you included the creepiest one, too, ha!